# Reduce multi-index/multi-level dataframe to single index, single level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
>>> df
   Year   MPG VehicleType FuelType
0  2000  20.5         Car      Gas
1  2009  22.3         Car      Gas
2  2017  50.9         Car      Gas
3  2000  14.7         Car   Diesel
4  2009  18.0         Car   Diesel
5  2017  22.2         Car   Diesel
```

I need to split the `VehicleType` column into two columns based on the value of the `FuelType` column, using the `Year` column as an index. I used `pivot_table` to split the columns correctly.

```
>>> pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['VehicleType', 'FuelType'], values='MPG', index=['Year'])
VehicleType    Car      
FuelType    Diesel   Gas
Year                    
2000          14.7  20.5
2009          18.0  22.3
2017          22.2  50.9
```

This is great and all, but it results in a multi-indexed dataframe, which for my purposes I don't want.

I am trying to get a result that looks *something* like this:

```
Year Car_Diesel_MPG Car_Gas_MPG
2000           14.7        20.5
2009           18.0        22.3
2017           22.2        50.9
```

My efforts at trying to achieve this have resulted in some pretty nasty looking code. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Using `set_axis`, `map`, and `join`

```
df2.set_axis(df2.columns.map('_'.join), axis=1, inplace=False).add_suffix('_MPG')

      Car_Diesel_MPG  Car_Gas_MPG
Year                             
2000            14.7         20.5
2009            18.0         22.3
2017            22.2         50.9
```

---

### `groupby` with a `dict`

```
m = {t: '_'.join(t) for t in df2.columns}
df2.groupby(m, axis=1).mean().add_suffix('_MPG')

      Car_Diesel_MPG  Car_Gas_MPG
Year                             
2000            14.7         20.5
2009            18.0         22.3
2017            22.2         50.9
```

---

Either of these can `reset_index`

```
m = {t: '_'.join(t) for t in df2.columns}
df2.groupby(m, axis=1).mean().add_suffix('_MPG').reset_index()

   Year  Car_Diesel_MPG  Car_Gas_MPG
0  2000            14.7         20.5
1  2009            18.0         22.3
2  2017            22.2         50.9
```

---

### `groupby` instead of `pivot_table`

```
df.groupby(
    ['Year', df.VehicleType.str.cat(df.FuelType, sep='_').add('_MPG').values]
).MPG.sum().unstack().reset_index()

   Year  Car_Diesel_MPG  Car_Gas_MPG
0  2000            14.7         20.5
1  2009            18.0         22.3
2  2017            22.2         50.9
```

Comment: Great answer, awesome examples. The pandas library is well documented, but sometimes I have no idea where to begin when looking at the documentation!

Comment: Glad to help (-:

Answer (score 10):

You could just concatenate the levels of your multiindex using `+`, and use that as the columns of your pivot table:

```
# Same as your original privot table:
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['VehicleType', 'FuelType'], values='MPG', index=['Year'])

df2.columns = df2.columns.get_level_values(0)+'_'+df2.columns.get_level_values(1)+'_MPG'

>>> df2
      Car_Diesel_MPG  Car_Gas_MPG
Year                             
2000            14.7         20.5
2009            18.0         22.3
2017            22.2         50.9
```

Answer (score 3):

We'll call you pivot table `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['VehicleType', 'FuelType'], values='MPG', index=['Year'])
```

Drop a level:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
df1

FuelType  Diesel   Gas
Year                  
2000        14.7  20.5
2009        18.0  22.3
2017        22.2  50.9
```

Now get rid of the `FuelType` label

```
df1.columns.name = None
df
     Diesel   Gas
Year              
2000    14.7  20.5
2009    18.0  22.3
2017    22.2  50.9
```

Comment: FYI the out put in not match with op's expected out put

Answer (score 3):

Using `str.join`

```
s=pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['VehicleType', 'FuelType'], values='MPG', index=['Year'])
pd.Index(s.columns).str.join('_')+'_MPG'
Out[9]: Index(['Car_Diesel_MPG', 'Car_Gas_MPG'], dtype='object')
s.columns = pd.Index(s.columns).str.join('_')+'_MPG'
s
Out[11]: 
      Car_Diesel_MPG  Car_Gas_MPG
Year                             
2000            14.7         20.5
2009            18.0         22.3
2017            22.2         50.9
```

Or `assign` the columns before you do `pivot`

```
pd.pivot_table(df.assign(Newcol=df['VehicleType'] + '_'+df['FuelType']+'_MPG'), columns=['Newcol'], values='MPG', index=['Year'])
Out[12]: 
Newcol  Car_Diesel_MPG  Car_Gas_MPG
Year                               
2000              14.7         20.5
2009              18.0         22.3
2017              22.2         50.9
```